# Processing only selected nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

An XSLT-newbie problem: I need to substitute a text value in XML-file. All other nodes must be left unchanged. Here's my input file (in.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <level1 attr1="val1">
        <level2>in</level2>
    </level1>
</root>
```

Here's my XSLT-transformation (subst.xsl):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="//node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/root/level1/level2/text()">out</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I run it with the following Ant-script (build.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="test" default="test" basedir=".">
    <target name="test">
        <xslt style="subst.xsl" in="in.xml" out="out.xml" />
    </target>
</project>
```

And here's what I get (out.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root>
    <level1>
        <level2>out</level2>
    </level1>
</root>
```

Attribute "attr1" of "level1" is missing.

I would be very grateful if anyone

- tell me **what's wrong with subst.xsl**

OR

- give me an idea how to force xslt-processor **just copy non-matched nodes** to output file and to do it by hand (which is in my case error-prone).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your identity transform is missing attributes (obviously). Use this instead:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Then, just add your last template.